# python to mysql unknown column in try exception

Tags: python, mysql

i just want to select or insert into mysql using python 3.2 and mysql.connector..

```
import mysql.connector
filename = "t1.15231.0337.mod35.hdf"
try:
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', database='etl')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM hdf_file WHERE NAMA_FILE = %s',filename)
rows = cursor.fetchall ()
if rows == []:
    insert_hdf = cursor.execute('INSERT INTO hdf_file VALUES(%s,null,NOW(),null,null,NOW())',filename)
    cursor.execute(insert_hdf)
    cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
```

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))

but it said that: unknown column 'filename' in where clause
i have tried to put something like this:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM hdf_file WHERE NAMA_FILE = filename')
```

but i got the same error...

Comment: try putting it like this `cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM hdf_file WHERE NAMA_FILE = %s',(filename,))`

Answer (score 0):

When using [`cursor.execute()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) with parameterised queries the query arguments are passed as a sequence (e.g. list, tuple) or as a dictionary if using named parameters. Your code passes only the string `filename`.

Your queries could be written like this:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM hdf_file WHERE NAMA_FILE = %s', (filename,))
```

Here the tuple `(filename,)` is passed to `execute()`. Similarly for the insert query:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO hdf_file VALUES (%s, null, NOW(), null, null, NOW())',
                   (filename,))
```

`execute()` will return `None`, so there is no use in storing the result in the `insert_hdf` variable. It also makes no sense, and will cause an error, if you attempt `cursor.execute(insert_hdf)`.